# java LocalDateTime from string parse error

Tags: java, datetime, parsing

It's my first question, but I try all day to find error:

I use simple code for parse DateTime from string:

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter=DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");
LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.parse("2019-12-01 10:00", dateTimeFormatter);
```

and got error:

> Text '2019-12-01 10:00' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain
>   LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {HourOfAmPm=10,
>   MinuteOfHour=0},ISO resolved to 2019-12-01 of type
>   java.time.format.Parsed

where is my mistake?

Comment: I know the error message is long and looks intractable at first. Try. Does this bit look right? `HourOfAmPm=10`?

Answer (score 3):

Use HH (hour-of-day).

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
```

Comment: I really can't figure out where the error here

Comment: My bad , try to use HH insted of hh.

Comment: I tried using HH, but the error is the same

Comment: @Eni, that can’t be. Please quote the (new) error message that you get when trying with uppercase `HH` instead of lowercase `hh`. When I paste the line from this answer into your code from the question, I get `start` equal to `2019-12-01T10:00` as expected.

Comment: friends, thank you for your quick help. The "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" works. This is all my fault for my inattention.